# Choose from session type from tty

Tags: login, wayland, tty, plasma, tiling

I am new to running native Ubuntu 22.04, only have used it with other distros on a WSL.
Is it possible to have my system boot to tty from where I can login to my user and then choose between a normal desktop KDE Plasma session, and a window manager like [Sway](https://swaywm.org/)?

The reason is because I want other people who are only familiar with desktop environments to be able to use Plasma.

Comment: I *love* my systems being multi-desktop & multi-WM systems, where I select which I use when I login. This is normally selected at the DM or login stage (ie. *greeter*) and not at terminal prompt; why not just let user(s) select at DM/greeter?  There are many DM/greeter choices.  FYI:  If I decide I want only a terminal/non-GUI system, I'll select that at `grub` before the system boots.. ie. normal procedures can be used; `sddm` being the DM normally used by Kubuntu, `grub` being default for all current Ubuntu systems - you didn't provide release thus I've kept this mostly generic.